# Changing charset/encoding on load() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, encoding, load

**Question:** How do you change encoding of text file that you are loading via jQuery's function `load()`?

I had 1 page, `index.html` in which I've put all my `css`, `js` and `html`, and now I want to "extract" the header of that page. I'm doing that by creating new folder named "header" which contains `header.css`, `header.js` and `header.html`. I am also creating a template (for all pages), that will include the header, and so, the `<head>` of this template looks like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="header/header.css" charset="windows-1252">
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="header/header.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>$(document).ready(function(){
               $('body').load('header/header.html');});
    </script>
</head>
```

This works well, and as I wanted it to, so there is no problem there.
**The problem** is that Serbian letters like š, đ, ž, č and ć are represented as question mark in black diamond (�). I did some research and found out that this is because browser* is expecting utf8 charset/encoding, and my files (listed above) are all **Windows-1252 encoded**. As you can see in code above, I did use `charset="windows-1252"`, but that is in `<link>`, which is a part of HTML, but to insert an existing page into template page, I have to use jQuery, and it can't select the encoding for the file it's loading.

**NOTE:** I am using **notepad++** and I did enshure that the encoding is windows-1252. Also, I'm using **Firefox** to preview my pages, and I found an article saying that firefox had some trouble with this encoding, but it was an old article.

Comment: Why don't you encode all your files and HTML page in utf8?

Comment: Because I'm using serbian letters like š, đ, ž, č and ć. I tought that I could use ANSI, but that one only has ž.

Comment: But utf8 should support these characters, not sure about windows-1252. What i told you was to use utf8, not windows-1252

Comment: Ok, I found out why I started using windows-1252. Its because ć and č are translated as c in utf8. I can use ž, but not other charactes. (I had to remove 2 comments in which I said it works now, because I wrote that before checking for other letters like š,đ,č and ć)

Comment: No, all these characters should  be supported AFAIK. Are you sure you reencode all your scripts in UTF8 (without BOM) and that you set in HEAD `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: @Monset, stackoverflow's encoding is UTF-8, and your characters appear here (as you can use) without any special conversion. Any chance you use some database and the database charset/collate/connection string is not set to utf-8?

Comment: Well, in notepad++ I can't even write ć or č when encoding is set to utf8
**EDIT** im not using any DB yet

Comment: @Monset, I'm using notepad++ and I don't have any problem wiring there any of your characters.

Comment: I will try creating new .html file and change encoding to utf8 only once (because I think I might ducked something up chaging the encoding so many times)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the encoding in `index.html`?

Comment: I had no reason to do so, so, nope.

Answer (score 0):

So... I found out what happened... Still don't know the reason, but now it works.

When I was changing the encoding in notepad++, I didn't click on `Convert to ___`, I clicked on `Encode in ___`. I changed the encoding like that multiple times, at last, changed it back to `utf-8`, but it still didn't work. Later, I noticed that there are two options: `Convert to ___` and `Encode in ___`, and then I went with `Encode in ___`. Now it works. When I say changed, i mean in all files (`header.html` `header.css` `header.js` and `template.html`). I don't know how `notepad++` works with encodings, but if anyone sumbles on the simmilar or the problem, the quick answer is:

**UTF-8 works fine. You dont't need 1252 nor 8859-1/2. If having trouble like me, in `notepad++` click `Convert to UTF-8` instead of `Encode in UTF-8`**.

Thank you for your suggestions, and sorry for this somewhat silly question. I just didn't know (and stil don't) the difference between `Convert to` and `Encode in` in `notepad++`.